# Dynamically generated select2 ajax trigger not working with no console log error

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I am using select2 of AdminLTE in my page.When I put dynamically created more than one select2 multi-select  ajax controls in a page, the controls do not work (the ajax request does not fire, no errors in console or network).

```
<pre>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

  <select id="filter_value_1"  class="chosen-select form-control 
 select2 filter_value fil_sel select2-hidden-accessible"></select>

 <select id="filter_value_2"  class="chosen-select form-control 
 select2 filter_value fil_sel select2-hidden-accessible"></select>

 <select id="filter_value_3"  class="chosen-select form-control 
 select2 filter_value fil_sel select2-hidden-accessible"></select>
 </pre>
```

Issue in populating data with no console error

Comment: 'It's not working' is a useless statement. What doesn't work? The instances of Select2, or the AJAX calls, or something else? Please check the console for a clue as to where the problem lies

Comment: No error showing in console and  ajax request does not fire too

Comment: Are you returning data from the AJAX call in the right format? https://select2.org/data-sources/ajax

Comment: yes. Its working for single select .

Comment: Could you please create fiddle for single working item ?

Answer (score 0):

I got a Solution from this link

https://forums.select2.org/t/preselecting-options-in-an-remotely-sourced-ajax-select2-with-custom-data-atribute/26

```
var sendurl ='http://...';
   for(var i=1;i<5;i++){
       var sSelect = $('#filter_value_'+i);
       $.ajax({
              type: 'GET',
              dataType: 'json',
               url: sendurl
       }).then(function (data) {
                 console.log(data);
             // create the option and append to Select2
            var option = new Option(data.text, data.id, true, true);
             $('.select2s').append(option).trigger('change');

          // manually trigger the `select2:select` event
            sSelect.trigger({
            type: 'select2:select',
            params: {
                data: data
             }
           });
         });
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per [document](https://select2.org/data-sources/formats), you need data in specific format only,

i.e. **id** and **text** pair

Example

```
{
  "results": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "text": "Option 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "text": "Option 2"
    }
  ]

}
```

URL `https://api.github.com/orgs/select2/repos` This does not have that kind of format, So first you need to format it.

I made some changes,

I hope this will solve your problem.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $('#filter_value_1').select2({
  ajax: {
 url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/select2/repos',
 dataType: 'json',
 processResults: function (data) {
    return {
   results: setData(data,'default_branch')
    };
  }
 }
});
function setData(data, text){
 for(i =0;i<data.length;i++){
  data[i]["text"]=data[i][text];
 }
 return data;
}

$('#filter_value_2').select2({
   ajax: {
 url: 'https://api.github.com/orgs/select2/repos',
 dataType: 'json',
 processResults: function (data) {
    return {
   results: setData(data,'description')
    };
  }
 }
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/select2/dist/css/select2.min.css">
<script src="https://adminlte.io/themes/AdminLTE/bower_components/select2/dist/js/select2.full.min.js"></script>

 <select id="filter_value_1" style="width:200px;"></select>
     <select id="filter_value_2"  style="width:200px;"></select>
```